# Pattern detection and splitting by space with exception

Tags: r, regex

Objective: detect a pattern and split it by a space, with an exception.

The illustrative example:

```
data <- c("redcat","big bobcat","bobcat","greencat","pinkcat","north cat")
```

I would like to retrieve all instances where `cat` is assembled with another word:

```
> data[grepl(".[a-z]cat$",data)]
[1] "redcat"     "big bobcat" "bobcat"     "greencat"   "pinkcat"
```

When found, each of the matches needs to be split by a space. The exception is `bobcat` which is another level and needs to remain unaltered.

The ideal result should be then:

```
[#] "red cat"     "big bobcat" "bobcat"     "green cat"   "pink cat"
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion based regex in `sub` or `gsub` function.

```
> data <- c("redcat","big bobcat","bobcat","greencat","pinkcat","north cat")
> gsub("(?<!bob)cat", " cat", data[grepl(".[a-z]cat$",data)], perl=T)
[1] "red cat"    "big bobcat" "bobcat"     "green cat"  "pink cat" 
> gsub("(?<!\\bbob)cat", " cat", data[grepl(".[a-z]cat$",data)], perl=T)
[1] "red cat"    "big bobcat" "bobcat"     "green cat"  "pink cat"
```

`(?<!\\bbob)cat` makes the regex engine to match all the `cat` except the one which was preceded by `bob`.

Apply the regex directly on `data`.

```
gsub("(?<!\\bbob)\\Bcat$", " cat", data)
```

Comment: Do you know all the languages? +1

Comment: ya. little bit in all the major lang... :-)

Comment: @Avinash: is there a way to add the space character _organically_? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by organically?

Comment: By a notation that corresponds to it. For instance, I just tested `[[:space:]]cat` but it returns "green[[:space:]]cat"...ect

Comment: ya, replacement part won't accept regex. you should use characters or backreferences or empty string only in the replacement part.

Comment: Ok, thanks. One more thing: how to replace the split levels in the dataframe `data`?

Comment: you may directly apply the regex directly on data `gsub("(?<!\\bbob)\\Bcat$", " cat", data)`

Comment: This is what I found works: `data[grepl(".[a-z]cat$",data)] <- gsub("(?<!\\bbob)cat", " cat", data[grepl(".[a-z]cat$",data)], perl=T)`. Is there a simpler way? Can you please add it to your answer. Thanks!